# No render data with React.js and Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I'm doing an example practice of how to connect react with redux and an external api to consume data.
By console in the payload I print correctly all the objects of the api but I can not paint it in the view. Any ideas?

I share a gist so you can see the example and it may be failing

I also share an image so that you see that in console if it shows the objects of the api

[Link Gist](https://gist.github.com/jmrosdev/5cee6c68833e0577466520ebc020d851)

[image]

Comment: have you done everything outlined here - https://medium.com/@paulfitzgerald_11524/quick-and-easy-guide-to-implementing-redux-in-a-react-app-5072e3a81b7a

Comment: In theory yes... I think the problem is a promise... I dont know :-(

Comment: could be as it looks good to me. If you can reproduce the project here I can take a look - https://codesandbox.io/s/new - i tried earlier but was missing a few files

Comment: It could be issues with your reducer. Try adding it to the gist

Comment: I can't find reducer file at [Link Gist](https://gist.github.com/jmrosdev/5cee6c68833e0577466520ebc020d851) and it seems you just use initialState as store.

Comment: @오현준 i update the Gist with files initialState and reducer. Any ideas?

Comment: @jpdelatorre i update the Gist with files initialState and reducer. Any ideas?

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald i update the Gist with files initialState and reducer. Any ideas? After the create project on platform what did you say

Comment: nothing solution?¿

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're not passing `action.payload` on your **LOAD_EXAMPLE_API** reducer.

```
//reducer
export default function apiExampleReducer(state = initialState.examples, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOAD_EXAMPLE_API:
      return {
        examples: action.payload,
        error: null,
        loading: false,
      };
    ...
  }
}
```